# Multipart form processing

Tags: java, forms, servlets, multipart

I am uploading an image file using commons fileupload, using post method. Image uploading is successful but when I try to access any other fields of the form using `request.getParameter("field_name");` method I get null values of all corresponding fields as result of which I am getting Exceptions of all kind. 
Here is the code of my form:

```
<form id="add-book" name="add-book" class="add-book" method="post" action="ServletImageUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td>field1</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Upload image</td>
           <td><input type="file" name="upload"  /></td>//image upload field
         </tr>

       <!--rest of the form fields -->
 </form>
```

So is the problem with the `request.getParameter();` method? Why am I not able to get the values of the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't use `request.getParameter()` when form is `multipart`. You can use [Apache Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) which provides API to parse a multipart request, and iterate through the parts of it individually.